# can I create a .xib from an implementation file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xib

I have a project that has the header and the implementaiton files and loads a plain old  UITableViewController from the .m but I have no way of configuring the View (I would like to do stuff like ad buttons and text fields onto the view instead of just having a table), should I create a .xib file so that I can modify the view? (Reason I don't just start a new project is that the current project has a bunch of other stuff like OAUTH processes that kick off at the AppDelegate stage to log a user into a system - and I need this functionality). So my question how can I create a .xib from the existing .m .h files and then add other objects which I can then code for.

Answer (score 1):

An answer from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225654/xcode-how-to-connect-xib-to-viewcontroller-class/18003928#18003928):

"Here's a more step-by-step way to associate your new UIViewController and .xib.

Select File's Owner under Placeholders on the left pane of IB. In the Property Inspector(right pane of IB), select the third tab and edit "Class" under "Custom Class" to be the name of your new UIViewController subclass.

Then ctrl-click or right-click on File's Owner in the left pane and draw a line to your top level View in the Objects portion of the left pane. Select the 'view' outlet and you're done.

You should now be able to set up other outlets and actions. You're ready to instantiate your view controller in code and use initWithNibName and your nib name to load it."

Comment: Thanks a lot, so to be precise, do you create a .xib first (lets call it "StartVC" and then select that StartVC.xib in the Project Navigator pane (PN) and THEN follow your two steps above?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a UITableViewController, simply create a new XIB file via Xcode (File -> New -> iOS -> UserInterface -> View) and then add set the file's owner to your subclassed UITableViewController.

You'll likely want to re-do how the user interface looks -- in terms of dropping objects like the table view and buttons or whatever else -- into the XIB's view.  It'll certainly save a lot of time versus trying to debug programmatically creating and adding subviews and actions.

And once that's in place, you can then make IBOutlets and IBActions to your heart's content.